# What does object._("a string here") mean?

Tags: java

I'm examining a source code written by someone else. I've encountered something like this:

```
x = new MyObject();
x._("somestring")
```

What does this expression object._("a string here") mean?

Comment: '_' is a valid identifier name, whether its a member variable or a function or something else

Comment: Even it is valid, this is *bad* (Java) style.

Comment: Indeed this is bad style, but it doesn't hurt to know what does the language support. :)

Comment: Whoever did this *will* burn in coder hell for that.

Comment: Maybe "whoever" is/was a Scala programmer ;-)

Comment: I've seen this used for methods of single-use-classes, for example Translator.translate('label_id') -> Translator._('label_id'). Not pretty, but it exists in the wild lands out there

Comment: The above stylistic outrage is misplaced. Such blanket statements with absolutely no context are a clear sign of inexperience. It is quite likely that this is the outcome of some kind of constraints.

Comment: If the `_` method deals with translation and i18n: there is a pretty wide-spread convention in the `C` world (e.g., http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Libraries), where string translation is handled using a macro called `_`. This convention was ported to other languages as well (e.g., Python, see the examples in http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Some stuff is never ever ever okay. As people who aren't inexperienced obviously know.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus I don't think I have encountered such a thing. For each thing there is a situation where it's the least terrible of available options. Sometimes you don't have much to choose from.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It simply means you have a method whose name is `_` in the class `MyObject` (or a superclass). There's nothing special, the `_` character just happens to be valid in Java names.

You might be surprised because you don't see that often. And you don't see that often because *"this practice is discouraged"*. It makes the code harder to read.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) :

> A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length
>   sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the
>   dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "_". The convention,
>   however, is to always begin your variable names with a letter, not "$"
>   or "_". Additionally, the dollar sign character, by convention, is
>   never used at all. You may find some situations where auto-generated
>   names will contain the dollar sign, but your variable names should
>   always avoid using it. A similar convention exists for the underscore
>   character; while it's technically legal to begin your variable's name
>   with "_", this practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted

Comment: And this method receives a `String` or a super class of it like `Object`.

Comment: Note that `x.π()` doesn't seem to be discouraged but I wouldn't encourage it either.

Answer (score 1):

Class `MyObject` has a method _() which accept `String` as input argument.

Comment: There is no evidence that the method is non-static.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik but any well written code following best practices would... hum, wait... ok...

Comment: @boxed__l No, you can call a static function on an instance. This is just bad practice (and it gets you a warning in most IDE).

Comment: @boxed__l supposedly it's there so you can refactor an instance method into static without changing all the calling code.